# How to release all keys

Tags: java, keypress

This code written in JAVA program I'm using this events to press Escape key and then to release the Escape key keyRelease "r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE); r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);" in for loop but upon execution of this code "Escape key" is executing twice. Kindly help

Comment: Please add some detail. What language are you using?

Comment: @ExP Im quite sure he is using java hence why there is a java tag. OP: You are using robot class right? Maybe show a little bit of code also before we can help you further